# How to install SQL Server Management Console in 2008 Express Version?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

I started a dozen attempts to install the SQL Server Management Studio for the 2008 Express Version of SQL Server.

What i use:
Windows Vista 2007 SP 2

What i did:
a) I downloaded the install file SQLManagementStudio_x86_DEU.exe from [Microsoft's Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/de-de/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b)

b) I started the setup and chose "Installation"/"Adding Feature"

c) The feature selection appears, but I can chose only from SQL Client Connectivity SDK

d) This is wrong I guess; but even if I click next I get an error message like "Please chose a feature first"

What can I do?

Thanks for any advice!!!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the size of the file you downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

Do any of these links help?

- http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-install-sql-server-management.html
- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bethmassi/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500441%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: I recommend the 2nd link.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL 2008 R2: During the installation process, at the `feature selection` screen, you will have to select `Shared Features > Management tools - Basic`. This will install SSMS onto your system.

If you did not do this during the initial installation, you can rerun the setup process and only select `Shared Features > Management tools - Basic`. This will then install SSMS on your server.